# Python Bokeh Hovertool with semi-transparent background

Tags: python, html, hover, bokeh

I wish to generate a scatterplot using [Bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/),
with a transparent / semi-transparent image as part of the [HoverTool](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#hovertool).

However, with my current implementation, both the html tooltip,
and the image inside it, are not transparent as shown below.

[image: Bokeh HoverTool]

The problem is that the image covers the data points
behind it. I wish to avoid reducing the image size,
as it would be harder to see.

Hence, I would like to know if it is possible to make
html tooltip semi-transparent (or transparent),
by modifying the following code below:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from bokeh.io import output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

def polar_plot(x, y, i, outfile):
    ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.plot([x[i]], [y[i]], 'bo')
    ax.set_rticks([-1, -.5, 0, .5, 1, 1.5])
    ax.grid(True)
    plt.savefig(outfile, transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.close()

x = np.linspace(0, 2, 21)
y = np.sin(x * np.pi)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': x,
    'y': y
})
df['filename'] = 'img' + df.index.astype(str) + '.svg'
df_cds = ColumnDataSource(df)

theta = x * np.pi
for row in df.iterrows():
    data = row[1]
    polar_plot(theta, y, row[0], data['filename'])

TOOLTIPS = f"""
<div style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);">
    <table style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);">
      <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="@filename"
                height="300" alt="@filename" width="300"
                style="float: left; margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px; background: transparent";
                border="1">
            </img>
        </td>
        <td>
        <span style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">x</span> = @x<br>
        <span style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">y</span> = @y<br>
        </td>
    </table>
</div>
"""

output_file('plot.html')

fig = figure()
fig.circle(x='x', y='y', source=df_cds)
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=TOOLTIPS)
fig.add_tools(hover)
show(fig)
```

Comment: Potentially, in principle. Have you tried applying various CSS rules for opacity, and it doesn't work?

Comment: setting "opacity: 0.2;" inside <style></style> tags makes the hovertool more transparent, but it apparently it does not allow the text / images behind the hovertool to become visible.

Comment: Did you [target the `img` elements directly](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp) as well?

Answer (score 0):

May be this is too late ...
here my solution add a callback to your tooltips.

```
callback = CustomJS(code="""  
document.getElementsByClassName('bk-tooltip'[0].style.backgroundColor="transparent";
""")
```

and then

```
HoverTool(tooltips=TOOLTIPS,callback=callback)
```